# Visual Studio Community for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2015

I am site administrator for one of the sharepoint 2013 on-premise site and I would like to develop the custom webparts for communicating lists and libraries at site level using visual studio Community 2015.
  Can anyone help me in knowing is it possible develop farm and sandbox solutions through visual studio 2015 community as it being providing free by microsoft.

Comment: Short answer is Yes. Just search this forum for details as the the question has been asked and answered a couple times already.